# Java Hibernate SQL Error: check right syntax to use near 'condition, description, name, pictures, price, status, User_UserAddress_idUserAd' at line 1

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I got an exception which is about the grammar I used for communicating with the data base (MySql) was wrong. I have checked my entity class and composite primary key class, and I could not find out the reason which causes the error which is shown here:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition, description, name, pictures, price, status, User_UserAddress_idUserAd' at line 1
```

Here is my Product class:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ProductPK.class)
public class Product {
    private int idProduct;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private double price;
    private String pictures;
    private int status;
    private int tradingAddressIdTradingAddress;
    private int condition;
    private int userIdUser;
    private int userUserAddressIdUserAddress;
    private int userSchoolIdSchool;
    private Collection<CategoryHasProduct> categoryHasProducts;
    private TradingAddress tradingAddressByTradingAddressIdTradingAddress;
    private User user;

    public Product() { }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idProduct", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public int getIdProduct() {
        return idProduct;
    }

    public void setIdProduct(int idProduct) {
        this.idProduct = idProduct;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "description")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "price")
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "pictures")
    public String getPictures() {
        return pictures;
    }

    public void setPictures(String pictures) {
        this.pictures = pictures;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "status")
    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "TradingAddress_idTradingAddress")
    public int getTradingAddressIdTradingAddress() {
        return tradingAddressIdTradingAddress;
    }

    public void setTradingAddressIdTradingAddress(int tradingAddressIdTradingAddress) {
        this.tradingAddressIdTradingAddress = tradingAddressIdTradingAddress;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "condition")
    public int getCondition() {
        return condition;
    }

    public void setCondition(int condition) {
        this.condition = condition;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "User_idUser")
    public int getUserIdUser() {
        return userIdUser;
    }

    public void setUserIdUser(int userIdUser) {
        this.userIdUser = userIdUser;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "User_UserAddress_idUserAddress")
    public int getUserUserAddressIdUserAddress() {
        return userUserAddressIdUserAddress;
    }

    public void setUserUserAddressIdUserAddress(int userUserAddressIdUserAddress) {
        this.userUserAddressIdUserAddress = userUserAddressIdUserAddress;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "User_School_idSchool")
    public int getUserSchoolIdSchool() {
        return userSchoolIdSchool;
    }

    public void setUserSchoolIdSchool(int userSchoolIdSchool) {
        this.userSchoolIdSchool = userSchoolIdSchool;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Product product = (Product) o;

        if (idProduct != product.idProduct) return false;
        if (Double.compare(product.price, price) != 0) return false;
        if (status != product.status) return false;
        if (tradingAddressIdTradingAddress != product.tradingAddressIdTradingAddress) return false;
        if (condition != product.condition) return false;
        if (userIdUser != product.userIdUser) return false;
        if (userUserAddressIdUserAddress != product.userUserAddressIdUserAddress) return false;
        if (userSchoolIdSchool != product.userSchoolIdSchool) return false;
        if (name != null ? !name.equals(product.name) : product.name != null) return false;
        if (description != null ? !description.equals(product.description) : product.description != null) return false;
        if (pictures != null ? !pictures.equals(product.pictures) : product.pictures != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result;
        long temp;
        result = idProduct;
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (description != null ? description.hashCode() : 0);
        temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(price);
        result = 31 * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
        result = 31 * result + (pictures != null ? pictures.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + status;
        result = 31 * result + tradingAddressIdTradingAddress;
        result = 31 * result + condition;
        result = 31 * result + userIdUser;
        result = 31 * result + userUserAddressIdUserAddress;
        result = 31 * result + userSchoolIdSchool;
        return result;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    public Collection<CategoryHasProduct> getCategoryHasProducts() {
        return categoryHasProducts;
    }

    public void setCategoryHasProducts(Collection<CategoryHasProduct> categoryHasProducts) {
        this.categoryHasProducts = categoryHasProducts;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TradingAddress_idTradingAddress", referencedColumnName = "idTradingAddress", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable =  false)
    public TradingAddress getTradingAddressByTradingAddressIdTradingAddress() {
        return tradingAddressByTradingAddressIdTradingAddress;
    }

    public void setTradingAddressByTradingAddressIdTradingAddress(TradingAddress tradingAddressByTradingAddressIdTradingAddress) {
        this.tradingAddressByTradingAddressIdTradingAddress = tradingAddressByTradingAddressIdTradingAddress;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "User_idUser", referencedColumnName = "idUser", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable =  false), @JoinColumn(name = "User_UserAddress_idUserAddress", referencedColumnName = "UserAddress_idUserAddress", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable =  false), @JoinColumn(name = "User_School_idSchool", referencedColumnName = "School_idSchool", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable =  false)})
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

And here is my ProductPK class:

```
public class ProductPK implements Serializable {
    private int idProduct;
    private int tradingAddressIdTradingAddress;
    private int userIdUser;
    private int userUserAddressIdUserAddress;
    private int userSchoolIdSchool;

    @Column(name = "idProduct")
    @Id
    public int getIdProduct() {
        return idProduct;
    }

    public void setIdProduct(int idProduct) {
        this.idProduct = idProduct;
    }

    @Column(name = "TradingAddress_idTradingAddress")
    @Id
    public int getTradingAddressIdTradingAddress() {
        return tradingAddressIdTradingAddress;
    }

    public void setTradingAddressIdTradingAddress(int tradingAddressIdTradingAddress) {
        this.tradingAddressIdTradingAddress = tradingAddressIdTradingAddress;
    }

    @Column(name = "User_idUser")
    @Id
    public int getUserIdUser() {
        return userIdUser;
    }

    public void setUserIdUser(int userIdUser) {
        this.userIdUser = userIdUser;
    }

    @Column(name = "User_UserAddress_idUserAddress")
    @Id
    public int getUserUserAddressIdUserAddress() {
        return userUserAddressIdUserAddress;
    }

    public void setUserUserAddressIdUserAddress(int userUserAddressIdUserAddress) {
        this.userUserAddressIdUserAddress = userUserAddressIdUserAddress;
    }

    @Column(name = "User_School_idSchool")
    @Id
    public int getUserSchoolIdSchool() {
        return userSchoolIdSchool;
    }

    public void setUserSchoolIdSchool(int userSchoolIdSchool) {
        this.userSchoolIdSchool = userSchoolIdSchool;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        ProductPK productPK = (ProductPK) o;

        if (idProduct != productPK.idProduct) return false;
        if (tradingAddressIdTradingAddress != productPK.tradingAddressIdTradingAddress) return false;
        if (userIdUser != productPK.userIdUser) return false;
        if (userUserAddressIdUserAddress != productPK.userUserAddressIdUserAddress) return false;
        if (userSchoolIdSchool != productPK.userSchoolIdSchool) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = idProduct;
        result = 31 * result + tradingAddressIdTradingAddress;
        result = 31 * result + userIdUser;
        result = 31 * result + userUserAddressIdUserAddress;
        result = 31 * result + userSchoolIdSchool;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here is where I save the product:

```
User user = getUserByUserId(session, userId);
Integer id = initiateTradingAddressForProduct(session);

Product product = new Product();
setProductBasicInfo(product, name, description, price, condition, status);
product.setTradingAddressIdTradingAddress(id);
product.setUserIdUser(userId);
product.setPictures("none");
product.setUserSchoolIdSchool(user.getSchoolIdSchool());
product.setUserUserAddressIdUserAddress(user.getUserAddressIdUserAddress());                 
session.save(product);
session.flush(); // The exception is thrown at this line
```

I do not know what reason causes those exception. Can someone help me to solve this problem? Thank you very much!

Updated:

```
Hibernate: 
    /* insert main.java.entities.Product
        */ insert 
        into
            Product
            (condition, description, name, pictures, price, status, User_UserAddress_idUserAddress, User_School_idSchool, User_idUser, TradingAddress_idTradingAddress, idProduct) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [5]
binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [very good]
binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [plane]
binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [none]
binding parameter [5] as [DOUBLE] - [132.0]
binding parameter [6] as [INTEGER] - [3]
binding parameter [7] as [INTEGER] - [11]
binding parameter [8] as [INTEGER] - [15]
binding parameter [9] as [INTEGER] - [57]
binding parameter [10] as [INTEGER] - [38]
binding parameter [11] as [INTEGER] - [0]
SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition, description, name, pictures, price, status, User_UserAddress_idUserAd' at line 1
```

I checked SQL in detail, and I thought all values are in positions where they should be. Also, I tried removing @id annotations, and that did not solve the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you are wanting multiple `@id`  annotations?

Comment: Check if you can get the complete sql that gets printed in debug mode, that might help you in getting to the error.

Comment: it is throwing an error at session.flush() because it is not getting the data that is currently in the session synchronized with what is in the database.I recommend you to see the pojo class and the database tables

Comment: Try to remove second `@Id` annotation

Comment: @deepakl I realized that the way you recommended is useful, and I am debugging right now.

Comment: @Akshay I checked tables, and I was sure that all required data is in the database.

Comment: @deepakl I updated my post, and I still could not figure out the problem. Do you have some comments on that?

Comment: @EugeneUstimenko I tried to remove Id annotations, but that did not work.

Comment: @YH.Liang - Now you have all the values and also the SQL, try to fire that that sql directly in the tool like toad, sql developer or any tool that you use... Do you get the error there also ? To me it seems there is some problem around 'User_UserAddress_idUserAddress" column or may be all columns starting with "User", I am telling you that because I can see those columns have a different colour from the rest of the columns...

Comment: How are you setting the dialect for Hibernate?  `condition` is a [MySQL reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html).  I would expect the correct Hibernate dialect to know about this and escape the column name as appropriate.

Comment: @deepakl Those values are with different colors because they are both primary keys for Product. Also, they are id from other tables.

Comment: @LukeWoodward I think your answer is very valuable. I did not set dialect for Hibernate. I think there is a high probability that the problem happens here.

Comment: @LukeWoodward Thank you very much! I solved my problem. You are right. "Condition" is the keyword in mysql, and I have to skip the reserved keyword for the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The problem is that the `condition` is the reserved keyword in MySql. If I use it for the name of the property, I have to escape that reserved keyword.

> How are you setting the dialect for Hibernate? condition is a MySQL reserved keyword. I would expect the correct Hibernate dialect to know about this and escape the column name as appropriate. @LukeWoodward

I got ideas from his answer, and the point he pointed was totally on the right direction. Anyway, thank you for everyone who answered this question.